# I want to remove special character from string but I need dot in string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My file name have some extra special character so I am trying to replace all special character with nothing .

My string is file name like Test(1).png

I want to remove special character but I need extension of file name. I tried below code:

```js
filename = filename.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '');
```

But I am getting **filename=test 1 png** and I want output like **filename=test 1.png**

Comment: did you try fileName.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9 .]+/g, '') ?

Comment: Then don't replace everything that is not a letter or a number. Replace everything that's not a letter, not a number and not the dot. It's adding one character in the code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Split the task in three steps :

1. Extract the extension in a variable
2. Use the line you wrote
3. Append the extension you saved

```js
var filename = 'text file 14 (2).png';
var extension = filename.substring(filename.length - 3); //IFF your extensions are always 3 longs
filename = filename.substring(0, filename.length - 4); //Remove the dot already
filename = filename.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '');
filename = filename + '.' + extension;

document.write(filename);
```

Comment: If you have variable length extensions, you can use split('.') to extract the extension. It's a bit more complex to write but fairly easy.